# Everything is wrong placed in Android Studio, while running it

Tags: java, android

If I try to run a normal quiz application from Android Studio everything like buttons are placed in one corner.
Does anybody knows how to solve that problem.

Comment: since this is not strictly a coding question, please provide a screenshot of Android Studio so we can at least see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you don't correctly configure the layout of the activity or fragment. If you are using a `ConstraintLayout`, you need to add constraints to each object within the layout or else it will default to the top left corner.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout